# Flutter project failing to build on Mac M1

Tags: xcode, firebase, flutter

I have recently bought a new Mac book with the [M1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_M1) chip and faced huge issues between Flutter and Firebase in building. I will list both the Flutter error log and Xcode error log.

Note: I'm building on Flutter channel *Master*

Flutter Error Log:

```
    Launching lib/main.dart on iPod touch (7th generation) in debug mode...
    Xcode build done.                                           69.1s
    Failed to build iOS app
```

Error output from Xcode build:

```
objc[30795]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both ?? (0x1fe91f8f0) and ?? (0x1189402b8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[30795]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both ?? (0x1fe91f940) and ?? (0x118940308). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
** BUILD FAILED **
```

Xcode's output:

```
/Users/wissamboughannam/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.6.7+1/ios/Classes/FLTImagePickerPlugin.m:141:20: warning: 'UIAlertView' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                   ^
In module 'UIKit' imported from /Volumes/Sub/Flutter-Projects/test-project/test_project_app_v2/test_app_2/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/image_picker/image_picker-prefix.pch:2:
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAlertView.h:27:12: note: 'UIAlertView' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
@interface UIAlertView : UIView
           ^
1 warning generated.
/Users/wissamboughannam/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.6.7+1/ios/Classes/FLTImagePickerPhotoAssetUtil.m:17:44: warning: 'UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 11.0 - Will be removed in a future release, use PHPicker. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  NSURL *referenceURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
                                           ^
In module 'UIKit' imported from /Volumes/Sub/Flutter-Projects/test-project/test_project_app_v2/test_app_2/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/image_picker/image_picker-prefix.pch:2:
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIImagePickerController.h:62:51: note: 'UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
UIKIT_EXTERN UIImagePickerControllerInfoKey const UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL API_DEPRECATED("Will be removed in a future release, use PHPicker.", ios(4.1, 11.0)) API_UNAVAILABLE(tvos); // an NSURL that references an asset in the AssetsLibrary framework
                                                  ^
/Users/wissamboughannam/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.6.7+1/ios/Classes/FLTImagePickerPhotoAssetUtil.m:21:47: warning: 'fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:options:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 11 - Will be removed in a future release [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  PHFetchResult<PHAsset *> *result = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:@[ referenceURL ]
                                              ^
In module 'Photos' imported from /Users/wissamboughannam/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.6.7+1/ios/Classes/FLTImagePickerPhotoAssetUtil.h:6:
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Photos.framework/Headers/PHAsset.h:74:1: note: 'fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:options:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
+ (PHFetchResult<PHAsset *> *)fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:(NSArray<NSURL *> *)assetURLs options:(nullable PHFetchOptions *)options API_DEPRECATED("Will be removed in a future release", ios(8, 11), tvos(8, 11)) API_UNAVAILABLE(macos);
^
2 warnings generated.
1 warning generated.
error: the following command failed with exit code 0 but produced no further output
CompileC /Users/wissamboughannam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-awkucyxpawezvvfjchbivjxuwsah/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/file_picker.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FilePickerPlugin.o /Users/wissamboughannam/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/file_picker-1.4.2/ios/Classes/FilePickerPlugin.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
/Volumes/Sub/Flutter-Projects/test-project/test_project_app_v2/test_app_2/ios/Pods/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore/Sources/FIRLogger.m:58:28: warning: this old-style function definition is not preceded by a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
void FIRLoggerInitializeASL() {
                           ^
/Volumes/Sub/Flutter-Projects/test-project/test_project_app_v2/test_app_2/ios/Pods/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore/Sources/FIRLogger.m:101:20: warning: this old-style function definition is not preceded by a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
void FIRResetLogger() {
                   ^
2 warnings generated.

/Users/wissamboughannam/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-3.2.0/lib/src/provider.dart:259:19: Error: The method 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.
 - 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/Users/wissamboughannam/Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType'.
        ? context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(type) as InheritedProvider<T>
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/wissamboughannam/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-3.2.0/lib/src/provider.dart:260:19: Error: The method 'ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.
 - 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/Users/wissamboughannam/Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType'.
        : context.ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType(type)?.widget
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Analyzing workspace
note: Constructing build description
note: Build preparation complete
note: Removed stale file
```

As for the Error log from Xcode:

```
/Users/wissamboughannam/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-3.2.0/lib/src/provider.dart:259:19: Error: The method 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.
 - 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/Users/wissamboughannam/Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType'.
        ? context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(type) as InheritedProvider<T>
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/wissamboughannam/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-3.2.0/lib/src/provider.dart:260:19: Error: The method 'ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.
 - 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/Users/wissamboughannam/Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType'.
        : context.ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType(type)?.widget
```

This is the main error, there were many warning, but I'm not sure if they're causing the build failure.

Running `flutter doctor` result:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 2.1.0-11.0.pre.227, on macOS 11.1 20C69 darwin-arm, locale en-SA)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.54.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Did you check your certificates? If you run `flutter build ios --verbose` do you get a message like "unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer ..."?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As we know that m1 mac runs on arm based processor and thus few things like cocoa pods and ffi needs to be build based on that.
After a long research i came up with few steps which will definitely help everytime you stuck with xcode flutter application build for m1 mac.

## To install completely cocoapods on Mac with M1 chip (Apple Silicon), please follow those steps:

## Cocoa Pods Installation in M1

- sudo gem install cocoapods
- sudo gem install ffi
- arch -x86_64 sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin
- sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin

## Install ffi

- sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi

#update repo

- arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update

## Flutter iOS builds

- flutter clean
- flutter build ios

## Re-install dependency in iOS folder of flutter project

- arch -x86_64 pod install

Answer (score 0):

I also have an M1 Mac, and am on the stable channel, without any errors.

Try switching to stable first.

Also, try running `$ flutter clean` and again building the app.

Comment: Thank you Kushal, but I have managed to figure it out, apparently the issue was with the depreciated context, after migrating all the packages I have managed to build on the dev channel and all works well now.

Answer (score 0):

I removed all depreciations and the project ran perfectly.

Comment: What is "depreciation" in this context?

Answer (score 0):

i had another issue related to flutter dependency that showing error *OBJC_CLASS* on firebase dependency, image cropper, stripe, etc.

My xcode disable archive & distribute menu because no successful build to archive.
I resolved it with this idea: build the app on terminal/android studio, then archive & distribute on xcode.

The step is:

**uninstall cocoapods**

`sudo gem uninstall cocoapods`

**install brew**

`/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`

`nano ~/.zshrc`

`export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"`

`brew --version`

**install cocoapods**

`brew install cocoapods`

`pod --version`

**link xcode**

`flutter doctor`

`sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

`sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch`

**go to your flutter project and**

`flutter clean`
`flutter pub get`
`cd ios`
`pod install`
`pod update`

open Runner.xcworkspace with xcode and set your signing & capabilities

open terminal on your flutter project and build

`flutter build ios --release`

This will build Runner.app

Go to xcode, on Runner choose any ios device (arm64), to enable archive.

Then

product-> archive->distribute app->next->manual signin->set your certificate distributor

This will build your .ipa