# iOS building issue - flutter

Tags: ios, xcode, building

I am using an M1 Mac.
Xcode version : Version 13.4.1 (13F100)

I don't know why the iOS build failed.
The android building is working well.

This is the terminal message.
Please help me...

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Upgrading contents.xcworkspacedata
Updating project for Xcode compatibility.
Upgrading project.pbxproj
Upgrading Runner.xcscheme
Upgrading Info.plist
Xcode build done.                                           103.6s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2022-06-20 12:33:31.094 xcodebuild[67910:9382087] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    2022-06-20 12:33:31.094 xcodebuild[67910:9382087] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/c0/5ywzpcwd47b5jd8k4q7gxrbw0000gn/T/flutter_tools.xFHKso/flutter_ios_build_temp_diro89ZzX/temporary_xcresult_bundle
/Users/vereup/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher-6.0.15/ios/Classes/FLTURLLauncherPlugin.m:140:57: warning: 'keyWindow' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 13.0 - Should not be used for applications that support multiple scenes as it returns a key window across all connected scenes [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                                                           .keyWindow.rootViewController];
                                                            ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/vereup/project/dukdoc-front-key/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/url_launcher/url_launcher-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:135:51: note: 'keyWindow' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @property(nullable, nonatomic,readonly) UIWindow *keyWindow API_DEPRECATED("Should not be used for applications that support multiple scenes as it returns a key window across all connected scenes", ios(2.0, 13.0));
                                                      ^
```

```
        ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/vereup/project/dukdoc-front-key/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/google_sign_in/google_sign_in.framework/google_sign_in, building for iOS Simulator-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for iOS Simulator-x86_64
        ld: in /Users/vereup/project/dukdoc-front-key/ios/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn(GIDEMMErrorHandler_3a47e13d8ca81b41e9cdb7ef5468004a.o), building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file '/Users/vereup/project/dukdoc-front-key/ios/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn' for architecture arm64
        clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
        note: Using new build system
        note: Planning
        note: Build preparation complete
        note: Building targets in dependency order
        Result bundle written to path:
            /var/folders/c0/5ywzpcwd47b5jd8k4q7gxrbw0000gn/T/flutter_tools.xFHKso/flutter_ios_build_temp_diro89ZzX/temporary_xcresult_bundle
    Error (Xcode): In /Users/vereup/project/dukdoc-front-key/ios/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn(GIDEMMErrorHandler_3a47e13d8ca81b41e9cdb7ef5468004a.o), building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file '/Users/vereup/project/dukdoc-front-key/ios/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn' for architecture arm64
    
    Could not build the application for the simulator.
    Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro.
    Exited
```

Comment: I solved with this !!!!! SO COOL!!!!! NICE!!!!!!!!!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66594590/flutter-project-failing-to-build-on-mac-m1